# Get WorkItems From Merge Changeset

Tags: tfs

I need to produce a list of Work Items from a production build, which is triggered by a merge. I use the below to get a list of changes, after pulling the Changeset Id from the build I care about

```
Uri tfsUri = new Uri("http://leecrp-tfs1:8080/tfs");
TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(tfsUri);
VersionControlServer vcs = tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

List<String> changedThings = new List<String>();
Build bld = _builds.Where(x => x.BuildNumber == buildNumber).First();

if(bld != null)
{
    int.TryParse(bld.SourceVersion, out int csId);
    if (csId > 0)
    {
        Changeset changeset = vcs.GetChangeset(csId);
        foreach(Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Change change in changeset.Changes)
        {
            changedThings.Add(change.Item.ServerItem);
        }
    }                
}

if(changedThings != null && changedThings.Count > 0)
{
    lbChanges.DataSource = changedThings;
}
```

However, there does not appear to be anything in the object about the source of each check-in. As stated, I primarily need the Work Items so I can link back to our JIRA tickets later.

I have tried the following, but it returns nothing

```
IEnumerable<ExtendedMerge> mergeDetails = vcs.QueryMergesExtended(new ItemSpec(@"$/Project/Branch", RecursionType.Full), VersionSpec.Latest, VersionSpec.ParseSingleSpec(csId.ToString(), null), VersionSpec.ParseSingleSpec(csId.ToString(), null));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, I just had to slightly modify an earlier attempt. The below gets me the merge details

```
VersionSpec versionSpec = VersionSpec.ParseSingleSpec(csId.ToString(), null);
ChangesetMergeDetails results = vcs.QueryMergesWithDetails(@"$/Project/SourceBranch", VersionSpec.Latest, 0, @"$/Project/TargetBranch", VersionSpec.Latest, 0, versionSpec, versionSpec, RecursionType.Full);
```

From there I use an excessive amount of `foreach` loops to get what I want:

```
foreach(Changeset thing in results.Changesets)
{
    foreach(WorkItem workItem in thing.WorkItems.Distinct())
    {
        changedItems.Add(workItem.Id.ToString());

        foreach (Revision revision in workItem.Revisions)
        {
            foreach (Field field in workItem.Fields)
            {
                if(field.Name == "History")
                {
                    string thingICareAbout = revision.Fields[field.Name].Value.ToString();
                    if (thingICareAbout.Contains("TFS4JIRA"))
                    {
                        wiHistory.Add(ParseJIRT(thingICareAbout));
                    }                                        
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```